# Getting the mean of a variable depending on other column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Basically what its on the title, I have a csv that I converted into a pandas dataframe that its something like this:

```
"ID","Name","Sex","Age","Height","Weight","Team","NOC","Games","Year","Season","City","Sport","Event","Medal"
"1","A Dijiang","M",24,180,80,"China","CHN","1992 Summer",1992,"Summer","Barcelona","Basketball","Basketball Men's Basketball",NA
"2","A Lamusi","M",23,170,60,"China","CHN","2012 Summer",2012,"Summer","London","Judo","Judo Men's Extra-Lightweight",NA
"3","Gunnar Nielsen Aaby","M",24,NA,NA,"Denmark","DEN","1920 Summer",1920,"Summer","Antwerpen","Football","Football Men's Football",NA
"4","Edgar Lindenau Aabye","M",34,NA,NA,"Denmark/Sweden","DEN","1900 Summer",1900,"Summer","Paris","Tug-Of-War","Tug-Of-War Men's Tug-Of-War","Gold"
"5","Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",21,185,82,"Netherlands","NED","1988 Winter",1988,"Winter","Calgary","Speed Skating","Speed Skating Women's 500 metres",NA
```

I would like to obtain the mean of 'Height' based on the Years like having the mean of the year 1992 and so on

Comment: Look into panda's `groupby` function. You'd tell pandas to _group_ your dataframe by year, and then you can do all sorts of functions based on groups, like finding the mean, the min, the max, etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want!!

```
df.groupby('Year')['Height'].mean()
```

How does it work? Initially, we group by a particular column (it's also possible to group by a set of columns). Then, we need to tell the column that we need to be group, in our case "height" followed by the criteria, here "mean".

Another syntax is as follows:

```
import numpy as np #Since there's no mean function in python
df.groupby('Year')['Height'].agg(np.mean)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!!!, Thanks a lot, now Im trying to a include this to a plot, but Im having an exception when assignin the dataframe to a variable :"KeyError: 'Year'"

Comment: That is because the 'Year' column is now in the index. You can do a `reset_index` to "send it back to the columns."

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
mean_height = df[df["Year"]==1992]["height"].mean()
```